# How to correctly launch a python application in the Mac OS X dock?

Tags: mac-osx, python, dock

I need to install a python application (python + wxWidgets GUI) to end users computers. I need an application to be in the Dock and start like any other application - with light "started" indicator, click-is-focus etc. However OS X prevents me from dragging the python script to dock - seems it thinks that python script is not an executable :(. When I drag a python script into "documents" section of dock it just don't start when clicked - an empty terminal opens, the python launcher opens for a few seconds and then nothing happens.

Using:
Mac OS X 10.5.7

Is there any way to put a python application into the Dock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [py2app](https://pypi.org/project/py2app/) to create MacOS apps from Python scripts.

Comment: All links dead.

Answer (score 1):

For the Dock in Mac OS X to think your application is a true Mac OS X application it needs to be an application bundle. Alternatively have you tried running it with a .command file instead? A user double clicks on the .command file and it will execute the instructions in Terminal - which may fix the issue you have but from your question I'm not sure why it would not be running correctly.

With the application in question have you looked at a modification to use [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)

Additionally, what about [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus)? If your script is making the app GUI after the fact or on it's own it may work. Just set Platypus to not show a GUI itself. (EDIT: Sorry - I forgot to mention this one originally)

Comment: The .command trick works, but it leaves parasitic terminal window at desktop. End users normally are not happy if they see some terminal windows running :). py2app seems like a solution, but it's very heavyweight: a lot of actions to do in order to perform a simple task :(. As i can see, where is no "wasy way" to run python app on MacOS? On windows i can just rename .py into .pyw and application will run as any normal windows application :(